# Excel solver macro offset and repeat

Tags: excel, vba, solver

Repeat excel macro solver every xx Rows with new reference

First time macro creator... I made a macro to run a solver. I have a similar solver running every 11 rows in my sheet and would like for the macro to update all solvers, not just the top one.

The one solver that is running off the macro solves for cell Q56 on the "menu" such that cell R56 will be set to zero. It sets r56 to 0 by changing q56.

I want to repeat this same process for later cells:
set r67 to 0 by changing q67,
set r78 to 0 by changing q78,
sets r89 to 0 by changing q89
etc., ending with setting r166 to 0 by changing q166

Is there a way to add an offset function that loops / repeats the solver that is in place for later cell references?

```
Sub AutoSolver1()

' AutoSolver1 Macro
    'Reset Solver
    'Solver Reset

    SolverOk SetCell:="$R$56", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Q$56", Engine _
        :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$R$56", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Q$56", Engine _
        :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
End Sub
```

The code i pasted will work for the top solver. i tried some variations to make it repeat for a new reference every 11th line but everything i have tried has yielded an error message

Comment: Set a variable to `range("R67")` use its address property in Solver and use the address of that variable , e.g. `r.offset(,-2).address`?

Comment: @SJR Thank you! much appreciated